# Subsetting in R gives same levels of a factor as before

Tags: r, levels

I have a typical problem. I have a dataset from which I have filtered the dataframe based on selected values in a column. When I check the levels it gives the same levels as before though the data frame does not show that. Please the images. 
The levels(gd2$Series) returns same levels as as levels(gd1$Series), why?
The code is as follows

```
gd <- read.csv("d3.csv")
names(gd) = sub("X","",names(gd))
levels(gd$Series)

names(gd)
sapply(gd, class)
gd1 <- gd[order(gd$Series),] 
rownames(gd1) <- NULL #reordering the rows
gd1[ gd1 == ".." ] <- NA

rownames(gd1) <- NULL #reordering the rows
levels(gd1$Series) # COMPARE THE LEVELS HERE WITH gd2$Series.

library(dplyr)
selected <- c("Air transport, freight (million ton-km)", 
          "Air transport, passengers carried",
          "Railways, goods transported (million ton-km)", 
          "Railways, passengers carried (million passenger-km)", 
          "Rail lines (total route-km)")


gd2 <- as.data.frame(gd1[gd1$Series %in% selected,])
levels(gd2$Series)
```

The data is downloadable from this link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtnYqHF_dUb1gdFSRkzrlSanIIbMPg
It is a small csv file.

[image: The gd2 Dataframe]

Comment: Filtering out some specific value does not result in the value being dropped from the levels of the factor. You could change that by using the `droplevels` command for the new series. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/droplevels

Comment: Thanks! Sorted out with `droplevels`, But my supplementary query is that should this be run on the concerned column only or for the entire dataframe.

Comment: I would say based on what you have provided, only on the column since it is the only factor column you have.